# Laravel database Migration on Heroku

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, laravel-artisan

I need to add a new table to my databases on a laravel project. However, I already have data in production and the code is deployed on heroku.

If I create a table on heroku and run a migration on heroku, that won't be reflected in my local code.

Is the proper method to create the table and migration in the local copy, push the code to heroku, and then run another migration on heroku?

If that is the case, do I first run something like this command to create the migration file, then edit the migration file to the table properties that I desire, and then push to heroku and run a migration or do I need to run a migration on my local copy first?

```
php artisan make:migration create_users_table --create=users
```

Thanks

Comment: it's best to do everything locally first. you can be sure that it's working and do want you need, and then push it to heroku and running the created migration

Comment: Your assumption is correct, but better to run it locally first just to be sure it will work. Also be sure to revise table structure before adding it.

Comment: So, I created the table locally and created a new migration at the same time, then I edited the properties of the table. The next step is to push the code to heroku and run what command? heroku run php artisan migrate?